# Silverlight 4 Databinding with Styles

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In my silverlight application I have a series of textboxes on a page that all bind the same way.  In the codebehind I am setting the datacontext of each one.  Has anyone incorperated this common binding functionality using styles?

Example
in my page.xaml

```
<TextBox Name="txtTest" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBoxInt}"/>
```

in my Styles.xaml

```
<Resource Dictionary>
<Style x:Key="ItemTextBoxInt" TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:n0\}}"/>
</Style>
```

this throws an error in the App.xaml.cs on startup

{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Set property '' threw an exception. [Line: 9 Position: 36] ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot set read-only property ''.
   at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at STARS_Silverlight.App.InitializeComponent()
   at STARS_Silverlight.App..ctor()}

Anyone know if this is possible and if so the correct way to accomplish this?

-Andrew

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately SL4 still does not support bindings in styles. Workaround: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Verify the `Amount` property has a publicly exposed setter.

Comment: the amount does have a public exposed setter. still throws the same error. :(